# bootstrap4 CDN, submit button not working

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

when I am giving the link manually, it working but when I am using the submit button its not working in Django.
Here is the code:

```
 <form method="get" action="/some/location/folder/" >
     <input type= "submit" class= "btn btn-info" style="float:right" value="New Folder" />
  </form>
```

what am i missing ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When you click the button it takes you to /some/location/folder/? If so, you can do 
`<form method="get">
     <input type= "submit" onclick="location.href='/some/location/folder/'" class= "btn btn-info" style="float:right" value="New Folder" />
  </form>`

Comment: Do you have an actual use case for submitting a form here, or is this essentially just a page you want to _link to_? If the latter, then this should not be done using a form in the first place, that makes little sense semantically. If you are doing it just for the optics of the submit button, then _format_ a normal link to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method from get, to post.